# Comparison without integration

Tags: integration

Can we tell $\int_{0}^{\pi/5} \sin^2 x \ dx < \int_{0}^{\pi/5} \sin^2 5x \ dx $ without integrating both like from plot?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: $\sin^25x-\sin^2x=\sin4x\sin6x$

Comment: Can we not be really simple and say that since both functions are positive over the given domain, the function which turns back towards the x-axis will create a smaller area than the one that keeps growing? (it makes sense geometrically when you think about it).

Comment: I am not able to derive the expression. Is it true sin^2 5x > sin^2 x in [0, pi/5]

Comment: Is $\sin^2ax=\frac{1-\cos2ax}{2}$ helpfull?

Comment: $\int_{0}^{\pi/5} \sin^2 x \ dx < \frac15\int_{0}^\pi\sin^2 y \ dy $ since $3\int_{0}^{\pi/5} \sin^2 x \ dx < 3\frac\pi5\sin^2\frac\pi5<\int_{\pi/5}^{4\pi/5}\sin^2 y \ dy$

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).